# How can I find out what the largest possible file-size for a given UIImage-size is?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimage, image-size

I am creating a turn based game, and using GameCenter to handle it. At one point here, I want to send a small picture/icon in the matchData for the match. This query has nothing to do with Game Center though, but since the Game Center matchData is MAX 64kb, I would like to know how to find out how much space an image CAN take up when it's x*x in size. I have tested with a couple of icons/images already, and they are very different in file-size. Two images, that were both 128x128 pixles, one was 13kb, the other was 34kb. I'm thinking they had different "resolutions" or something(pixels per inch?) as well as I'm guessing some colors are 'bigger' than others, but I would like to know how to find out how big I must EXPECT the files to be (always assume the worst, right?).
I have already made a cropping-tool, so that the image is always 128x128, **is there a way to know how big(in bytes) a 128x128 image CAN be?** And if they have a "resolution" at a million, how can I reduce that programmatically?(Note that I have absolutely no idea what this "resolution" really is)

With white having the RGB code of 255,255,255, where as 255 actually is an entire byte, will that mean that a completely white image of 128x128 pixels (16,384 pixels) uses three bytes(R,G,B) per white pixel(total=49,2kb)? I'm obviously guessing NO, as a completely black image would have the total size of 0b. And what is this "resolution" that often is 72, what does that mean? I've used `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);`to put the images in an NSData so far, and I've tried other values, like `0.1f`.

**Bonus question:**

Here I noticed some weird behavior:

```
//Original image at 128*128px
UIImage *image1 = [player getImage];

//Convert image to NSData with compression quality at 0.1
NSData *imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.1f);

//Print out the file size of the image:
NSLog(@"Image size after 0.1: %@", [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:imageData1.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);

//Convert back to UIImage from this NSData
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData1];

//Convert again, back to NSData, now with compression quality at 1.0 (full?)
NSData *imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 1.0f);

//Print out the file size of this as well:
NSLog(@"Image size after 0.1 THEN 1.0: %@", [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:imageData2.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);

//Result:
/*
Image size after 0.1: 5 KB
Image size after 0.1 THEN 1.0: 34 KB
*/
```

If I change the first conversion to 1.0 instead of 0.1, it also prints out `34 KB`. Am I not converting from 0.1 to 1.0? Is it somehow returning the quality? Or are these only pointers, and nothing really happens? I've tried displaying the images, and I can't see any difference between the two, so either it won't display, or there's something funky going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because a byte isn't 255 doesn't mean that it is not using a full byte.  Computers can't understand partial bytes (as far as I know).  A black pixel in a 32-bit bitmap is 4 bytes.  A white pixel in a 32-bit bitmap is 4 bytes.  A transparent pixel in a 32-bit bitmap is 4 bytes.

Furthermore a UIImage *never* has any compression on it.  It is always an uncompressed 24-bit or 32-bit bitmap.  Graphics hardware cannot understand normal file compression schemes like JPEG or PNG.  So what you are doing in your "weird" code (which is actually completely normal behavior) is this:  taking a UIImage and compressing it, then uncompressing it, then compressing it again.  At that size, you are not likely to notice a difference in JPEG quality though.

Currently, in practice, the highest resolution of an image is 1 byte per channel, with 4 channels (red, blue, green, alpha).  That means that the highest possible size of a 128x128 image is 128x128x4 bytes, or 64 Kb.  For JPEG images, I doubt it will ever get this high though (the goal of image compression is to avoid this high file size while still saving as much quality as possible).  The reason for the variance has nothing to do with "pixels per inch," that is only relevant for display hardware and printers.  It has to do with the fact that some patterns are more easily compressed than others.  For example, a solid red square will be much smaller than a photo of your cat.

72 is the dots per inch (DPI) value of the image.  This is only relevant for printing or for displaying an image in inches instead of pixels.  When you want to print something, you specify the size in inches while the picture's size is measured in pixels.  Thus, you will end up with a certain number of pixels in every inch.  72 pixels in an inch is the standard for display, while 300 is (or at least was the last time I checked) the standard for printing.

Comment: Wow. The aforementioned 34Kb-image I've been testing with actually IS a photo of my cat....   Anyway, when I compress the original image, I'm imagining I am squeezing two similar pixels that are next to each other together, and that leaves ONE color for both of them, so that the data can say "here lies two pixels of color green", but only saves one green as reference. So when I uncompress it again, it actually creates two green (now identical) pixels? Or am I way off? So in my case, the first 34Kb and the second 34Kb is not the same? Then I still don't understand the difference of 5Kb and 34Kb

Comment: If both the 5Kb and the 34Kb images are 128*128 pixels, then what makes the 34Kb-version bigger than the 5Kb-version, when it had no more information to uncompress from than 5Kb? Where does the data come from?

Comment: The compression amount (0.1 vs 1.0, which corresponds to 10% quality and 100% quality) is the cause of the size difference.  Also, the compression scheme is much more complex than what you have mentioned.  In very basic terms, it creates pixel clusters out of groups of pixels.  However, at the end of the day computers can basically only display bitmaps so it has to decode that info.  It tries to recreate the data as accurately as possible, but you still end up with the same number of uncompressed bytes (even if they are both green).  Repeatedly compressing *will* result in artifacts, but...

Comment: The filesize will only vary slightly.